# How to do network request without clicking at button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a textfield and I need that when I write smth. in textfield it sends request to server without clicking at any button. For example if my sending text is the same as server's text it print that text. I am using SwiftUI and Combine. Below is my code.

```
@State var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
     .onReceive(Just($homePageVM.orderNumber)) { res in
            if !homePageVM.orderNumber.isEmpty {
                cancellable = homePageVM.orderNumber
                    .publisher
                    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                        print(completion)
                    }, receiveValue: { value in
                        homePageVM.getVoucherInfo { result in
                            if homePageVM.orderNumber == homePageVM.getVoucherInfoModel?.orderNumber {
                                print(result)
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
```

I am using *onreceive* because I need to send the data every time i change the text. But in the result i receive an unended cycle. How can i send data only one time every time I change my text? Please help me.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Every time you change `orderNumber`, you go fetch some information with `getVoucherInfo` that then sets `orderNumber` again -- thus the infinite loop. Are you sure you don't want to store the fetched data in some *other* variable?

Comment: You can check [this article](https://onmyway133.com/posts/how-to-debounce-textfield-search-in-swiftui/) using debounce . You can adjust the delay after you type before making action.

Comment: thanks a lot, that is exactly what i was searching @PtitXav

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange to use `onReceive` with `Just` and `sink`, there is no point in using Combine at all. The `onChange` modifier would replace all of this. However, the best way to do what you need simply with multiple View structs and the `task` modifier, e.g.

```
struct View1: View {

    ...

    var body: some View {
        View2(orderNumber: model.orderNumber)
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    let orderNumber: Int
    @State var result: String?

    // body called when any of the properties change
    var body: some View {
        Text(result ?? "No result")
        .task(id: orderNumber) { newOrderNumber in
            result = await fetchVoucherInfo(orderNumber: newOrderNumber)
        } // The `task` is started if the orderNumber has changed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is also a good solution to me, i will try and use it. @malhal